# Adding Logical Constraints in PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to add alloys to steel in order to bring carbon content of steel to a certain range, at minimal cost.
But one limitation is that in real life, the machine can only add a minimum of 50kgs of an alloy. So if we are adding a certain alloy, then it can be either 50/60/70 kgs etc. or 0kgs if we are not adding that particular alloy. How would I add a constraint for the same?

Thanks in advance!

Below is the function I've written:

```
def optimizer_pd(test):

    # declare problem
    prob = LpProblem("Minimize Alloy Cost",LpMinimize)

    # percentage of carbon in each alloy
    percs = ele_percs['carbon']
    
    # alloy_vars is a list of all possible alloys
    
    # constraints
    prob += lpSum([percs[i] * alloy_vars[i] for i in alloys]) >= minimum_carbon
    prob += lpSum([percs[i] * alloy_vars[i] for i in alloys]) <= maximum_carbon


    # objective function
    prob += lpSum([costs[i] * alloy_vars[i] for i in alloys])
    
    # solving
    sol = prob.solve()
    
    # results
    var_dict = {}
    for var in prob.variables():
        var_dict[var.name] = var.value()

    return var_dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

In the future, you'll get better answers if you present a minimum *reproducible* example for what you are trying to do.  But, it is clear enough from what you post.

So, you will need to introduce an extra helper or "indicator" **binary** variable, indexed by your alloys to do this.  This yes/no variable indicates the commitment to use at least the minimum amount of the alloy.  (You essentially need to break your requirement into 2 variables....)

Then you will need to use a "big M" constraint on the amount to use (or just use the max value).  In pseudocode:

```
use[alloy] ∈ {0,1}
amount[alloy] ∈ non-negative reals
min[alloy], max[alloy] are fixed min/max parameters
```

Minimum use constraint:

```
amount[alloy] >= use[alloy] * min[alloy]   for each alloy
```

Maximum use constraint:

```
amount[alloy] <= use[alloy] * max[alloy] (or big M)  for each alloy
```

Plug in a few numbers to ensure you "believe it"  :)