# Pyomo: How to include a penalty in the objective function

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm trying to minimize the cost of manufacturing a product with two machines. The cost of machine A is $30/product and cost of machine B is $40/product.

There are two constraints:

- we must cover a demand of 50 products per month (x+y >= 50)
- the cheap machine (A) can only manufacture 40 products per month (x<=40)

So I created the following Pyomo code:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.y = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)

def production_cost(m):
    return 30*m.x + 40*m.y

# Objective
model.mycost = Objective(expr = production_cost, sense=minimize)

# Constraints
model.demand = Constraint(expr = model.x + model.y >= 50)
model.maxA = Constraint(expr = model.x <= 40)

# Let's solve it
results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)

# Display the solution
print('Cost=', model.mycost())
print('x=', model.x())
print('y=', model.y())
```

It works ok, with the obvious solution x=40;y=10 (Cost = 1600)

However, if we start to use the machine B, there will be a fixed penalty of $300 over the cost.

I tried with

```
def production_cost(m):
  if (m.y > 0):
    return 30*m.x + 40*m.y + 300
  else:
    return 30*m.x + 40*m.y
```

But I get the following error message

```
Rule failed when generating expression for Objective mycost with index
    None: PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (0  <
    y) to bool. This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable
    Param in a Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking
    container membership or equality. For example,
        >>> m.x = Var() >>> if m.x >= 1: ...     pass
    and
        >>> m.y = Var() >>> if m.y in [m.x, m.y]: ...     pass
    would both cause this exception.
```

I do not how to implement the condition to include the penalty into the objective function through the Pyomo code.

Comment: This is a job for a “Big M” constraint to cover a fixed startup cost.  (Do a little google search or look it up in a linear programming text.)  Here is an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69659608/adding-logical-constraints-in-pulp/69665636#69665636.  Essentially, you need to introduce an additional binary variable in a clever way.  You cannot use `if` statement in model construction based on variable value as it is unknown when model is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `m.y` is a `Var`, you cannot use the `if` statement with it. You can always use a binary variable using the `Big M` approach as Airsquid said it. This approach is usually not recommended, since it turns the problem from LP into a MILP, but it is effective.

You just need to create a new `Binary Var`:

```
model.bin_y = Var(domain=Binary)
```

Then constraint `model.y` to be zero if `model.bin_y` is zero, or else, be any value between its bounds. I use a bound of 100 here, but you can even use the demand:

```
model.bin_y_cons = Constraint(expr= model.y <= model.bin_y*100)
```

then, in your objective just apply the new fixed value of 300:

```
def production_cost(m):
    return 30*m.x + 40*m.y + 300*model.bin_y 

model.mycost = Objective(rule=production_cost, sense=minimize)
```

Comment: Thank you @pybegginer, very well explained :-) 
I will go deeper into the use of Big M.

Comment: For unbounded `Vars` you need to use a very large value of bound, such as `1E6`. In this kind of problem, you will need to double check the solver tolerance to Binary, since it might happens that `bin_y` is approx. zero, but `y` is still greater than zero: for instance, if bounds are set as 1E6 and the binary tolerance is 1E-6, `bin_y` is assigned to 1E-7(very near to zero) but the resulting constraint is `y<=5` allowing Y to be larger than zero. Anyhow, just double check those values when model is solved