# How to implement a piecewise battery efficiency function in Pyomo (using ipopt solver)?

Tags: if-statement, pyomo, piecewise, ipopt

I am trying to use a piecewise function which describes the efficiency of a battery energy storage system (BESS) in a *pyomo* optimization concrete model.

The efficiency piecewise function is defined as follows:

[Piecewise Efficiency Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOjG4.png)

The dynamic efficiency assumes a different value for each time step t, since it is a function of the normalized power rate (P_rate(t)): it corresponds to the power level of the battery at each time t, divided by the BESS nominal power. Its equation is reported here:

[Normalized Power Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYbQ6.png)

The developed Pyomo concrete optimization model has the goal to maximize the BESS net profit while providing energy arbitrage service. The dynamic piecewise efficiency function "model.eff[t]" is a component of the objective function.
Here it is reported the portion of the code with the optimization procedure:

```
# Definition of the degradation cost
degrade_cost = [alpha_degradation * (model.energy_out[t] + model.energy_in[t]) for t in model.T] # [$]

# Definition of the Export Revenue, Import Cost and Net Profit
export_revenue = [price_df.iloc[t, -1] * model.energy_out[t] *  self_discharge_losses * model.eff[t] for t in model.T] # [$]
import_cost = [price_df.iloc[t, -1] * (model.energy_in[t] / model.eff[t]) * self_discharge_losses for t in model.T] # [$]
profit_ts = np.array(export_revenue) - np.array(import_cost) - np.array(degrade_cost) # [$]

profit_obj = np.sum(profit_ts) # [$]

# Declaration of the objective function
model.objective = Objective(expr = profit_obj, sense = maximize)

sol = SolverFactory('ipopt')
sol.solve(model, tee = True)
```

1. As a first attempt, I tried to create an external function named "calculate_efficiency" that is imported and called back to the battery MILP class (main code) where the pyomo concrete model is developed.
   This "calculate_efficiency" function is reported here:

```
def calculate_efficiency(energy_num):
    
    a1_coeff = 5.5
    a2_coeff = 0.53
    
    b1_coeff = 2.5 
    b2_coeff = 0.71
    
    c1_coeff =0.875
    c2_coeff =0.84
    
    d1_coeff = 0.5 
    d2_coeff = 0.885 
    
    e1_coeff = 0.037
    e2_coeff = 0.959
    
    f1_coeff = -0.05
    f2_coeff = 0.985
    
    g1_coeff = -0.082
    g2_coeff = 1.00697
    
    if energy_num >= 0 and energy_num < 0.06 and energy_num:
        eff = a1_coeff * energy_num + a2_coeff
        
    elif energy_num >= 0.06 and energy_num < 0.08:
        eff = b1_coeff * energy_num + b2_coeff
                    
    elif energy_num >= 0.08 and energy_num < 0.12:
        eff = c1_coeff * energy_num + c2_coeff
                    
    elif energy_num >= 0.12 and energy_num < 0.16:
        eff = d1_coeff * energy_num + d2_coeff
                    
    elif energy_num >= 0.16 and energy_num< 0.295:
        eff= e1_coeff * energy_num + e2_coeff
                    
    elif energy_num >= 0.295 and energy_num < 0.6965:
        eff = f1_coeff * energy_num + f2_coeff
                    
    elif energy_num >= 0.696 and energy_num <= 1:
        eff = g1_coeff * energy_num + g2_coeff
                    
    return eff
```

Passing now in the main pyomo code, the update of the efficiency is done imposing the following constraint:

```
from BESS_Efficiency_Curve import calculate_efficiency

# 11th Constraint: energy_cycle_rate_per_ts
# This constraint calculates the energy/power rate at each time step t in per unit terms and it will be used to evaluate the dynamic efficiency eff[t].
def energy_rate_per_ts(model,t):
    ts_energy = ((model.energy_out[t] + model.energy_in[t]) / self.pwr)
    return model.energy_rate[t] == ts_energy 
model.energy_rate_per_ts = Constraint(model.T, rule = energy_rate_per_ts)
        
# 12th Constraint: update_eff
# This constraint elavuate the dynamic efficiency at each time step t calling back the the calculate_efficiency function. 
def update_eff(model, t):
    calc_eff = calculate_efficiency(model.energy_rate[t])
    return model.eff[t] == calc_eff
model.update_eff = Constraint(model.T, rule = update_eff)
```

The 11th constraints allows to evaluate "model.energy_rate[t]" that corresponds to the normalized power rate (P_rate(t)) previously defined.
While the 12th constraint permits to evaluate an efficiency value for each time step t according to the power rate value.
Adopting this first attempt, the following error appears:

```
PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (0  <=  energy_rate[0]) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality. For example,
m.x = Var()
if m.x >= 1:
    pass
and
m.y = Var()
if m.y in [m.x, m.y]:
    pass
would both cause this exception.
```

As stated here ([Pyomo: How to include a penalty in the objective function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065978/pyomo-how-to-include-a-penalty-in-the-objective-function)) and here (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/use-if-statements-when-defining-a-constraint-in-pyomo), I cannot use the **IF** statement in model construction based on a variable (model.energy_rate[t]) that is unknown when model is built. In fact, the **IF** statement is for programming, not for use in mathematical programming equations.

2. To resolve this issue, I converted the "calculate_efficiency" function in an explicit form, as reported here:

```
def calculate_efficiency(energy_num):
    
    
    efficiency =  0.003707 * energy_num ** 9 - \
    0.009836 * energy_num ** 8 - \
    0.006317 * energy_num ** 7 + \
    0.02882 * energy_num ** 6 + \
    0.002729 * energy_num ** 5 - \
    0.03291 * energy_num ** 4 + \
    0.002599 * energy_num ** 3 + \
    0.008697* energy_num ** 2 - \
    0.01535 * energy_num + \
    0.9597
    
    
    return efficiency
```

By implementing this explicit equation derived by fitting the piecewise function previously defined with the **IF** statements, the *pyomo* model works and the optimization problem is correctly solved using *ipopt* as solver.
The problem now is that, when the normalized power rate is equal to zero, the efficiency assumes the value of the last fitting coefficient (0.9597) and the efficiency function does not correctly works for low power rates close to zero.
Therefore, the piecewise efficiency function defined using the the **IF** statements is necessary to solve the problem with the correct efficiency values.

3. As third attempt I tried to replace the **IF** statements by adopting the bigM method and introducing in this way 7 binary variables. Here it is reported the bigM procedure:

```
a1_coeff = 5.5
a2_coeff = 0.53
        
b1_coeff = 2.5 
b2_coeff = 0.71
        
c1_coeff = 0.875
c2_coeff = 0.84
        
d1_coeff = 0.5 
d2_coeff = 0.885 
        
e1_coeff = 0.037
e2_coeff = 0.959
        
f1_coeff = -0.05
f2_coeff = 0.985
        
g1_coeff = -0.082
g2_coeff = 1.00697
        
model.bool1= Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool2 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool3 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool4 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool5 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool6 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0) 
model.bool7 = Var(model.T, within = Boolean, initialize = 0)

# 11th Constraint: energy_cycle_rate_per_ts
# This constraint calculates the energy/power rate at each time step t in per unit terms and it will be used to evaluate the dynamic efficiency eff[t].
def energy_rate_per_ts(model,t):
    ts_energy = ((model.energy_out[t] + model.energy_in[t]) / self.pwr)
    return model.energy_rate[t] == ts_energy 
model.energy_rate_per_ts = Constraint(model.T, rule = energy_rate_per_ts)

def cal_eff_1(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.06 - M * (1 - model.bool1[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= a1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + a2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool1[t]))
model.cal_eff_1 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_1)
        
def cal_eff_2(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.06 - M * (1 - model.bool2[t]) 
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.08 + M * (1 - model.bool2[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= b1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + b2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool2[t]))
model.cal_eff_2 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_2)
        
def cal_eff_3(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.08 - M * (1 - model.bool3[t])
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.12 + M * (1 - model.bool3[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= c1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + c2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool3[t]))
model.cal_eff_3 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_3)
        
def cal_eff_4(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.12 - M * (1 - model.bool4[t])
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.16 + M * (1 - model.bool4[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= d1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + d2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool4[t]))
model.cal_eff_4 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_4)

def cal_eff_5(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.16 - M * (1 - model.bool5[t])
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.295 + M * (1 - model.bool5[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= e1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + e2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool5[t]))
model.cal_eff_5 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_5)  
        
def cal_eff_6(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.295 - M * (1 - model.bool6[t])
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 0.6965 + M * (1 - model.bool6[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= f1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + f2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool6[t]))
model.cal_eff_6 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_6) 
        
def cal_eff_7(model, t):
    M = 1e06
    model.energy_rate[t] >= 0.6965 - M * (1 - model.bool7[t])
    model.energy_rate[t] <= 1 + M * (1 - model.bool7[t])
    return ((model.eff[t]) <= g1_coeff * model.energy_rate[t] + g2_coeff + M * (1 - model.bool7[t]))
model.cal_eff_7 = Constraint(model.T, rule = cal_eff_7) 

def Eff_bool(model, t):
    return (model.bool1[t] + model.bool2[t] + model.bool3[t] + model.bool4[t] + model.bool5[t] + model.bool6[t] +                 model.bool7[t], 1)
model.Eff_bool = Constraint(model.T, rule = Eff_bool)
```

Adopting this bigM method, the model is solved until reaching the 879th iteration, but after that the following error appears:

```
Number of Iterations....: 879

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   3.7024308277601292e+06    4.0857717441143915e+06
Dual infeasibility......:   4.8094614069316000e+13    5.3074216467503102e+13
Constraint violation....:   3.4581735069731074e+01    3.4581735069731074e+01
Variable bound violation:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   3.5471221015941129e-01    3.9143827203882148e-01
Overall NLP error.......:   9.3107153980596161e+09    5.3074216467503102e+13


Number of objective function evaluations             = 1270
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 636
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1270
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 1270
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 886
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 886
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 880
Total seconds in IPOPT                               = 29.736

EXIT: Restoration Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):

  

ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error
```

How can I introduce this piecewise efficiency function defined using **IF** statements without using the **IF** statements, since they are not supported by Pyomo?

I would appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.
If you need more details about the code, please ask me.